# How do I easily know whether a win32 api is implemented in python and how to know which module to import

Tags: python, winapi

I use pywin32-216.win32-py2.7.exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ , and hope to use Win32 API GetCPInfoEx(). However, `import win32api` seems does not provide that function.

BTW: Is there more official python win32 api package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there more official python win32 api package?

What you are looking for is [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).